# Why at the school not at school

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence why is it at *the* school not at school?

> They don't have to do their homework today because it's a holiday at the school.

Comment: Because *the school*, as an institution, has declared it a holiday. So no one is there. Which means the holiday isn't occurring on school grounds. It's abstract, not physical.

Comment: The real question is why they didn't just say "because it's a school holiday".

Answer (score 3):

In the US, we'd simply say 'it's a *school holiday*'. ***"At school"*** would be used to describe a 'school function':

"The football team had their first practice ***at school***, today."

"***At school***, we sometimes start fires in science class."

But - (*not* school functions)

"The Ladies' Auxiliary Committee will meet ***at the school***."

"There was a fire ***at the school***, that practically destroyed the gymnasium."